# Visual Studio 2015 run script/code while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When debugging SqlQueries in visual studio 2015 the lowest level of code that I can easily access is a function call of the form:

```
executeSql(string sqlQuery, SqlParams[] params);
```

When debugging this I sometimes need to manually run the query. To do this I manually copy the query string and SqlParameters however, copying the sqlParams can take alot of time depending on how many there are as I need to copy each individually plus add the type of parameter.

I wanted to know if it was possible to print the SqlParams array as valid Sql statements (Declare/Set) without modifying the underlying code at all. Essentially I want to be able to right click on the variable and run a script that will generate SQL statements for each parameter in the array. I can easily write the script but I'm not sure how I would run it on the variable when the debugger is paused. Is this sort of functionality possible in VS 2015?

A rough example of the script would be:

```
foreach(SqlParameter p in __variable__){
    print("Declare " + p.ParameterName + " ");
    switch(p.SqlDbType){
        case System.Data.SqlDbType.Char: 
            print("char;"); 
            break;
        case ..
    }
    print("\nSet " + p.ParameterName + "'" + p.SqlValue + "';\n");
}
```

Comment: If you create a function which does what you need, then you can execute it from the Immediate pane on VS. Immediate pane allows you to execute any arbitrary code while the debugger is paused.

Comment: That did the trick. My only complaint is that the output in the immediate pane is unformatted ('\n' is not converted to newline) so I need to process the results again in notepad++. Also the same functionality can be achieved from the command window.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting @Gusman's comment in an answer:

If you create a function which does what you need, then you can execute it from the Immediate pane on VS. Immediate pane allows you to execute any arbitrary code while the debugger is paused.